# xslt get the ancestor folder path

Tags: xslt, xpath

Is there a good way to get the base uri and get the folder path of that ancestor?

```
<!--xslt2.0-->
<xsl:message select="base-uri()" />

<!--out-->
<!--file:/D:/works/ancestor/parent/index.xml-->


<!--I want to read the ancestor file in the ancestor folder.-->
<!--I want to derive this from the value of the base-uri().-->
<xsl:message select="document('file:/D:/works/ancestor/ancestor.xml')" />
```

Regerds

Comment: There is a `resolve-uri` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-resolve-uri you can use. On the other hand, as you use the `document` function, it has a second argument to provide a node whose base URI then serves to resolve relative URIs in the first argument so I am not sure you need any more than `document('ancestor.xml', .)`

Comment: I tried them but it did not work.
It can not specify an ancestor with a relative path(?)
A FileNotFoundException will occur.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve or what are the difficulties, give the base URI you have shown you can use `resolve-uri('../ancestor.xml', 'file:/D:/works/ancestor/parent/index.xml')` to get `file:/D:/works/ancestor/ancestor.xml`. Does that help?

Comment: I was able to solve with resolve-uri ('../ ancestor.xml', 'file: / D: / works / essestor / parent / index.xml'). I am very grateful to you. It solved it before writing the answer...